# User-selected marker in time series data in Java

Tags: java, graphics, plot, time-series

My code plots 5000 points of time series data in a panel that is 581 pixels wide by default, but this width changes when the user resizes the window.  My code also plots several rectangular markers that each identify a local maximum/peak in this same space.

I need to enable the user to right click on any of the rectangular-peak-markers so that the user can manually delete any false peak.  The problem is that my code is reporting different x-coordinates than expected when the user right-clicks on a peak-marker.  I suspect that the reason may have to do with rounding error in converting from 581 x-pixels back to 5000 data indices.  But I am not certain of the reason.

Can anyone suggest a solution that enables my users to manually select one of the above-described peak markers by right-clicking on it?

I am enclosing relevant sections of the code below.  My actual code is very, very long, and too complicated to post.  But the relevant portions below should be enough for someone to see the logic of my approach, and to then suggest a more effective approach.

The code that declares the class in question is:

```
class SineDraw extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {
// lots of code, including the two segments excerpted below
}
```

This segment of code overloads the paintComponent of the JPanel so that my data is plotted:

```
// declare some variables
ArrayList<Double> PeakList = new ArrayList<Double>()  // this ArrayList is populated by an extraneous process
visiblePoints = 5000
hstep = getWidth()/visiblePoints //=581/5000 by default, but will change when user resizes window
int numPeaks = PeakList.size();

// scale (y-coordinate) data relative to height of panel
pts = new double[visiblePoints]
for (int i = 0; i < pts.length-1; i++){pts[i]=//data vertical scaled to fill panel;}

// plot the 5000 time-series-data-points within the 581 pixels in x-axis
for (int i = 1; i < visiblePoints; i++) {
    int x1 = (int) ((i - 1) * hstep);
    int x2 = (int) (i * hstep);
    int y1 = (int)pts[i - 1];
    int y2 = (int)pts[i];
    g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

// plot a rectangle for each of the local peaks
for(int m=0;m<=(numPeaks-1);m++){
    if(i==(int)(PeakList.get(m)){
        int currentVal = (int)pts[(int)(PeakList.get(m)];
        g2.drawRect((int)(PeakList.get(m), currentVal, 6, 6);
    }
}
```

This section of code is for handling the right-clicking of the mouse:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    // check to see if right mouse button was clicked
    boolean jones = (e.getModifiers()&InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK)==InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK;
    if(jones==true){
        // test the value returned as x-coordinate when user right-clicks (code always underestimates x-coordinate of local peaks by this test)
        double ReverseHstep = visiblePoints/getWidth();
        int getX_ConvertedTo_i = (int) (e.getX()*ReverseHstep);
        System.out.println("getX_ConvertedTo_i is:  "+getX_ConvertedTo_i );

        // check to see if peaklist contains a value within the x-coordinates of the user-selected-rectangle
        if(PeakList.contains((double)(e.getX()-3))
                ||PeakList.contains((double)(e.getX()-2))
                ||PeakList.contains((double)(e.getX()-1))
                ||PeakList.contains((double)(e.getX()))
                ||PeakList.contains((double)(e.getX()+1))
                ||PeakList.contains((double)(e.getX()+2))
                ||PeakList.contains((double)(e.getX()+3))
                ){
                // handling code will go here, but for now it is a print test that never succeeds because x-coordinate is always underestimated
                System.out.println("You just selected a peak!");
        }
        }
    repaint();
    }
```

Comment: I have been testing this, and the x-coordinates I am getting by right-clicking are each between 92.7% and 93.8% of the expected values from the corresponding peak in the PeakList ArrayList.  This argues that the problem may be due to systematic rounding error.

Comment: How many rectangles are you drawing? If not too many, you could potentially make each rectangle a separate object and have them listen for a click event. Then it wouldn't matter "where" it was drawn.

Comment: I have about 3 million data points, in which there are perhaps 3500 local peaks who each need their own rectangle. At any given moment, only 5000 data points are plotted in the JPanel, and there might be 5 to 15 local peaks in that 5000 datapoint window, but there is a scrollbar on the bottom of the panel that allows the user to scroll through the 3 million data points to see all 3500 peaks.  The JPanel is repainted when the user utlizes the scrollbar.

Comment: Nice, nevermind then! My Swing is a bit rusty, maybe you could test for the color of that specific pixel? That is, if peaks can be identified that way.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler, Are you willing to show me an example of code to make each rectangle a separate object that listens for a click event?  I am tempted to take that approach for the 10 or so rectangles that will be plotted in the screen, and then perhaps just delete the irrelevant objects each time the user scrolls to a different section of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create objects (in this case `Rectangles`) for each thing you want to be clickable. Here is an over-simplified example of how you can make something you draw clickable. The key thing to take away from this is the `mouseClicked` method which will display a dialog *only* if the mouse clicked within the rectangle.

One tricky point is that I wasn't able to figure out how to make the rectangle filled in with color without drawing another rectangle over it. I'll leave that one for you ;-)

```
public class Canvas extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    private Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100,100);

    public Canvas(){
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        rect.setSize(100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setClip(rect);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        if(rect.contains(e.getPoint())){
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Click!");
        }
    }

    // The rest of the MouseListener methods have been cut out

    public static void main(String[] a){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Canvas Thingy");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);
        frame.add(new Canvas());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you.  It looks like I have to create a separate JPanel for every marker on my time series data that I want to be clickable.  (5 to 15 small marker-panels, each placed on the larger data panel where my 5000 data points are also plotted.)  I say this because, when I try to alter your code to extend Rectangle instead of extending JPanel, I get error messages telling me that Rectangle does not support the relevant methods.

Comment: I was implying that your Canvas could have a List of Rectangles.

Comment: I am working on this again now, and may have further comments/questions as I get further into it.

Comment: Thanks.  I got your suggestion working in a practice "sandbox."  When I integrate it into my larger application, it is still giving me problems with converting from the 581-wide-pixel coordinates to the 5000 plotted points.  But I think I can fix that with more time.  So I am marking your answer as correct.  Your answer has at least enabled me to focus the problem to the point where I can think of a number of possible solutions on which to work tomorrow.  I am going to mark this question as closed now.